# Error 1248: Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql

Please see my [code](http://pastie.org/10253839), below. I get the error:

> Error 1248: Every derived table must have its own alias

What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `insert_seance` (IN compared_id INT)
BLOCK1: BEGIN
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE log
    LIKE seance_log;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE compared_log
    LIKE seance_log;
BLOCK2: BEGIN
    DECLARE done, inner_done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE diff BOOL DEFAULT TRUE;
    DECLARE current_id, se_id, q_id, ans INT;
    DECLARE compared CURSOR FOR
        SELECT seance_id, question_id, answer FROM seance_log
        WHERE seance_id = compared_id;
    DECLARE seance CURSOR FOR
        SELECT seance_id FROM seances
        WHERE seance_id <> compared_id;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN compared;
    WHILE NOT done DO
        FETCH compared INTO se_id, q_id, ans;
        INSERT INTO compared_log (seance_id, question_id, answer)
            VALUES (se_id, q_id, ans);
    END WHILE;
    CLOSE compared;
    SET done = FALSE;

    OPEN seance;
    WHILE NOT done DO
        FETCH seance INTO current_id;
        DELETE FROM log;
        BLOCK3: BEGIN
            DECLARE answers CURSOR FOR
                SELECT seance_id, question_id, answer FROM seance_log
                WHERE seance_id = current_id;
            DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET inner_done = TRUE;
            DELETE FROM log;
            OPEN answers;
            WHILE NOT inner_done DO
                FETCH answers INTO se_id, q_id, ans;
                INSERT INTO log (seance_id, question_id, answer)
                    VALUES (se_id, q_id, ans);
            END WHILE;
            CLOSE answers;
            SELECT IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT 'log' AS `set`, l.*
                FROM log l
                WHERE ROW(l.seance_id, l.question_id, l.answer) NOT IN
                (SELECT * FROM compared_log)
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'compared_log' AS `set`, cl.*
                FROM compared_log cl
                WHERE ROW(cl.seance_id, cl.question_id, cl.answer) NOT IN
                (SELECT * FROM log)
                )),FALSE,TRUE) INTO diff;
            CASE WHEN diff = FALSE
                THEN DELETE FROM seance_log
                    WHERE seance_id = compared_id;
                UPDATE seances SET count = count + 1
                    WHERE seance_id = compared_id;
            END CASE;
            SET done = NOT diff;
        END BLOCK3;
    END WHILE;
    CLOSE seance;
END BLOCK2;
END BLOCK1
```

Comment: @HoboSapiens specially for guys who haven't heard of hyperlinks >_<
pastie.org/10253839

Comment: @Hobo Sapiens there is link if you press word code

Comment: Adding a bit of background in the question explaining what are you trying to do and what is failing,not just title + code + not working, would improve quality of the question.

Comment: @user3360241 I am trying to do a bunch of things. I don't want to explain anything because I know enough to be sure that in this particular case **purpose means nothing**. Your request to clarify things is like a question "What are you going to do?" from ISP tech-support. You see, if the there is a problem connecting to Internet it does not matter at all. Same here. I didn't say "not working", you can look up edits history. From the very beginning I named the error that happens